# How to use UrlFetchApp.fetchAll with Calendar API in google workspace addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-workspace-add-ons

Our Google Workspace Addon synchronises calendar events from Google Calendar to an external database.

As part of this process we update multiple Calendar Events using the patch command

```
Calendar.Events.patch({extendedProperties:pp},_e.calendar.calendarId,_e.calendar.id);
```

The problem we have is that we need to perform this operation multiple times within a limited amount of time (app script will time-out)

We could achieve this with the **UrlFetchApp.fetchAll** function but unfortunately to call this we would need to call the calendar api directly.  Although this is easily done - we do not have the AccessToken as this is not available and is handled by the API.

Does anybody know how to get the accessToken (without pushing the user through a separate OAuth approval process) that is being used by the Calendar API so that we can utilise it to call **UrlFetchApp.fetchAll**

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, about `without pushing the user through a separate OAuth approval process`, for example, can you use the service account in your situation?

Comment: In addition to what @Tanaike mentioned, which type of account do you have, consumer or workspace?

Comment: I'm think that you should be able to enable the api in the cloud console and also add it to your project.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, we do not have the accessToken in the workspace Add-on, this is all managed seamlessly by Google.  We could however separately request permission to the calendar api, but this would require us to get each user to grant access through an OAuth 2 Access process.  We don't want to do this.  Likewise we could use a service account but again this would require some form of separate authorization.

Comment: @JoseVasquez both account types are supported.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `but this would require us to get each user to grant access through an OAuth 2 Access process. We don't want to do this.`, in this case, even when the service account can be used, it is required to share the calendar with the service account. At this time, authorization is required to be done. So I thought that this method, which uses the service account, might not be suitable. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have the correct Calendar scope in your add-on, I think you can just pass [`ScriptApp.getOauthToken()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getoauthtoken) as the token in the `UrlFetchApp` request:

> #### `getOAuthToken()`
>
> Gets the OAuth 2.0 [access token](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.4) for the effective user. If the script's OAuth scopes are sufficient to authorize another Google API that normally requires its own OAuth flow (like [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs)), scripts can bypass the second authorization prompt by passing this token instead. The token expires after a time (a few minutes at minimum); scripts should handle authorization failures and call this method to obtain a fresh token when needed.
>
> The token returned by this method only includes scopes that the script currently needs. Scopes that were previously authorized but are no longer used by the script are not included in the returned token. If additional OAuth scopes are needed beyond what the script itself requires, they can be [specified](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes) in the script's manifest file.
>
> **Return**
>
> `String` — A string representation of the OAuth 2.0 token.

#### Example Request:

```js
function patchCalendarEvents() {
  const calendarId = "calendarId"
  const eventIds = [] // your event ID list
  const baseUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events/{{eventId}}`
  const requests = []

  eventIds.forEach(function (event) {
    requests.push({
      "url": baseUrl.replace("{{eventId}}", event),
      "method": "PATCH",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      },
      "payload": '{"extendedProperties": {"shared": {"testKey": "Test Value"}}}',
      "contentType": "application/json",
    })
  })
  console.log(requests)

  const responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests)

  responses.forEach(function(response) {
    console.log(response.getContentText())
  })
  
}
```